# Polygons disappearing after using the splitting tool in QField

Tags: qgis, editing, splitting, qfield

I am trying to make a QField project which can be used for mapping the vegetation types in nature areas. For some projects I have received a polygon shapefile with the old data. So, I want to edit the polygons and update the attribute values.

When I use the split tool in QField to edit a polygon, one of the created polygons disappears after editing the attribute values. After exporting the QField project in QGIS on the desktop, the polygons are still missing.

For some reason this does not happen with all the polygons.

Does anyone know the reason and the solution for this issue?

Comment: Are you changing some attribute that is used to style the polygon? So afterwards there is no style specified for that attribute value